# Text To speech feature on selected text

Tags: text-to-speech, text-selection

I wonder if there is ability to replicate this feature from iOS :

[image: iOS text to speech selection]

In iOS you can turn on Accessibility function that add the "Speak" button to the "selection menu". And if you click, it would turn on Text To Speech engine and read selected text. Can I do the same thing in Android ?

Thank you very much in advance

PS: I assume that regular app could not modify "copy, paste, cut menu" so I probably need custom ROM.

Comment: Not that directly, maybe – but would a "talking clipboard" be an acceptable work-around? I.e. something that speaks what you copy to your clipboard, or export via the share menu?

Comment: @Izzy Of course it would be acceptable :) Yes, share button works with "Talk - Text to voice" app. It is not super comfortable but it works. "speaking everything what is in clipboard" would be more comfortable... :]

Comment: OK, in that case I've just added a few hints in an answer. Hope one of them proves useful for your purpose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you had in mind, but coming close: There are several clipboard-action apps available which might come close to that. I didn't try them, so no guarantees – but their descriptions are promising they can do that. Two examples would be:

- [Speaklip](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Speaklip/com.aps.speakanything)
- [Auto Speak Clipboard 2](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.chungsdoors.android.asc2)

Hopefully one of them proves helpful to you. Good luck!

Comment: Glad to read – enjoy :)